# How can I set the position of the table with ItextSharp/C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, position, itext

I am writing a windows form code for making offers for my clients. I want it to make pdf file.
I do know how to position text. I do know how to make a table, and fill it with content from my datagridview.

But how can I position this table in the middle of the page vertically (not horizontal alignment - i know this), or in any predefined position? Below is my code. The result is that a table is directly at the top of page, even if I put some text by SetTextMatrix somwhere in the middle of the page. Should I make some big, transparent row or something?

```
PdfPTable tabela = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);

    float[] szerokości = new float[] 
    {
      dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width
    };

    tabela.SetWidths(szerokości);
    tabela.HorizontalAlignment = 1; // 0 - lewo, 1 - środek , 2 - prawo
    tabela.SpacingBefore = 10.0F;

    PdfPCell komorka = null;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
      komorka = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(c.HeaderText, czcionkaNaglowek)));
      komorka.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
      komorka.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
      tabela.AddCell(komorka);
    }

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
          komorka = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), czcionkaTabela));
          komorka.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
          komorka.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
          tabela.AddCell(komorka);
        }

      }

    }

    oferta.Add(tabela);
    oferta.Close();
  }
  catch (DocumentException dex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(dex.ToString());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: How did you get this far with the code you just posted..? have you been to iTextsharps web site they have numerous examples

Comment: Well, I goole a lot and search stackoverflow. I am really suprised that my program turned out thery good, except of this table postioning.

Comment: `+1`I am impressed you actually put in some great effort but I know that the iTextSharp has some good examples I use to use it a few yrs back but don't anymore..

Comment: Thank you. I went through loading excel to datagrid, datagrid filtering on textbox text change and some other problems - in most cases I googled some ideas. But here I'm stuck. Did not find anything on iTextSharp website that I could use her. I'll wayt a week and will just try to add blank rows of text so table will start lower...But it will not be elegant solution ;)

Comment: what do you mean start lower..? can you filer or create a query or do some sort of paging that will allow for the results that you want to  capture in the PDF..?

Comment: What I want to put the table more or less in the middle of the page. When i make pdf, in upper part are some client info and below that should be the table. But since i use .SetTextMatrix(x, y) for this info when I put a table with code up there, it is not below this text but direcly under top margin of the page. I need to start from more or less middle of the page.

Comment: Ah, the solution was so simple. I just put top margin at 400 points, and its just what I needed. Table starts at the midle of the page. Now I need to make it tidy. Next step: export to excel.

Comment: Export excel stuff should not be that hard there are a lot of Interop examples on this site as well or are you exporting the file(s) as `.CSV` which in some instances is 100 times easier ..LOL

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to finish this program this week. I'll export to xls file since this is a format used my company.